# Migration Assistant multiple use

Tags: migration, migration-assistant

Is it possible to use the migration assistant to transfer files from my old PC to a new Mac (OSCatalina) more than once? I've got around 300gb of data on my old pc and transferred just 50gb to start with so that I don't have to wait for days to finish, but now when I open the migration assistant it says that the migration is "complete" and does not allow me to conduct a second transfer.

Is there any way to do another migration?

Thanks!

Comment: What's exactly installed on your old PC: macOS or Windows or something else and which version?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'get out of jail free' card would be if all you have left to transfer are some simple stand-alone documents, rather than user-specific data, email accounts, browser logins & passwords etc. You could then just network the two together & file-share, rather than migrate.

Each migration will set up a new user account on your new Mac.
Your current stumbling block is you would have to keep generating new names. As soon as you do, it will let you proceed - but don't do that.
Picking this apart manually afterwards is going to be an absolute nightmare.*

Set aside sufficient time to be able to do this in one go & start over. Wipe the Mac & install a fresh new OS. Do the full migration as soon as it asks you, when you're initialising for first use.
You will be considerably better off in the long run.

*Been there, done that, don't ever want to do it again.

The procedure to do a full reset is at Apple KB - [What to do before you sell, give away, or trade in your Mac](https://support.apple.com/HT201065) In essence, you want to handle this as though you are going to be the 'next user'.

Comment: Amazing - many thanks! I decided to network the two together. The best I came up with was setting up a free trial dropbox which allows me to get 3tb worth of info on the cloud. Upload on one, download on the other.